# Converting millisecond UTC to Human Readable Date_Time

Tags: c++, time, boost-date-time

I'm struggling to figure out how to preform a conversion with boost::date_time.
I want to convert a millisecond value measured from the Unix epoch (00:00, Jan 1, 1970)  to a human readable string - something like: `2/13/2012 15:20:11` would be ideal.

I've tried some std C++ / boost suggestions I've seen but not had any luck just yet. Here is the code I use:

```
    long long ticksFromEpoch = 1329117220501;

    std::time_t tt = static_cast<time_t>(ticksFromEpoch);

    boost::posix_time::ptime dt = boost::posix_time::from_time_t(tt);

    // Create a time_zone_ptr for the desired time zone and use it to create a local_date_time
    boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr zone(new boost::local_time::posix_time_zone("UTC"));
    boost::local_time::local_date_time dt_with_zone(dt, zone);

    std::stringstream strm;

    strm.imbue(std::locale(std::cout.getloc(), new boost::local_time::local_time_facet("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))); // 15:14
    strm << dt_with_zone;

    // Print the stream's content to the console
    std::cout << strm.str() << std::endl;
```

The output is: `2032-07-01 20:20:37` which is clearly incorrect. I suspect that I'm not constructing the `ticksFromEpoch` variable correctly but I'm not sure why. Can anyone point me in the right direction? Any help is much appreciated!!

Comment: Boost solution for Windows and posix posted [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916071/converting-datetime-to-different-timezone-in-c-boost/9274998#9274998

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`time_t` is usually seconds since "the epoch", rather than milliseconds.
If you dont care about milliseconds you should be able to do this:

```
std::time_t tt = static_cast<time_t>(ticksFromEpoch/1000)
```

If you do care about milliseconds you can either add them back in at the end (which is tricky to get right for times like 12:00:00.001 AM )

Or you'll need to go another route. You may need to use something like this: (untested)

```
boost::posix_time::ptime t2(
  boost::gregorian::date(1970,boost::date_time::Jan,1),  //The epoch
  boost::posix_time::seconds( ticksFromEpoch / 1000 ) + // Number of seconds
  boost::posix_time::milliseconds( ticksFromEpoch % 1000)  // And the micros too.
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, Michael! Your initial observation worked. almost. `std::time_t tt = static_cast<time_t>(ticksFromEpoch/1000);`
but the result still seems to be 8 hours behind my locale.

Comment: @Frank, your ticks must be UTC ticks then (which is correct for posix time). Switch to local time using the timezone functions found here: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_48_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html

Comment: Again thank you for your input! Perhaps I don't understand the docs correctly but it seems that I need to specify the timezone explicitly with something like `"MST-07"` whereas I am looking for something that deduces the timezone it lives in dynamically as my system will run in a number of different timezones.

Comment: In order to dynamically deduce the timezone I had to use the following  C code: 

    `time_t  now = time(NULL);
    struct tm tnow = *localtime(&now);//gmtime(&now);
    char    buff[100];
    strftime( buff, sizeof buff, "%a %b %d %Y %T %Z%z", &tnow );
    printf( ">>%s<<\n", buff );` which does get the system timezone required. Cheers...