# Does CONVERT_TZ take daylight saving into account?

Tags: mysql, date, time, convert-tz

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL CONVERT_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)

Does CONVERT_TZ take daylight saving into account?

For example:

`CONVERT_TZ('2013-1-1 12:00:00', 'US/Pacific', 'UTC');`

I got the correct result, but I am not sure how to test DST scenario.

Comment: Choose a date in the summer when DST is in effect?

Comment: Heh, touché. Lemme try that :)

Comment: According to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3703030/679449) it does.

Comment: Voted to close. Exact duplicate