# how to get result of one day in different timezones - php/mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table with `GMT timezone`. Now i require to get results from different timezone.

if i search date `04-02-2013`  all result will be in GMT and after converting to particular timezone it may have `05-02-2013.`

so. I require a exact result of date `04-02-2013` for a particular timezone. for example `+5:30` offset.(ie between `GMT +5:30 and -5:30`)

How to write for in mysql.

Comment: convert_tz() of mysql http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Comment: use mysql function `convert_tz`

Comment: but how to write convert_tz() in where clause.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datefield,'US/Eastern','US/Central');
```

Found on: [MySQL CONVERT_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)

Comment: but how to write a query for this, like--> "select * from records where date = CONVERT_TZ(datefield,'US/Eastern','US/Central')";

Answer (score 0):

check this page of mysql offiicial website

```
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz
```

Comment: but if the query is " select * from records where date = CONVERT_TZ(datefield,'US/Eastern','US/Central')"; .... ?

Comment: `select * from records where date = CONVERT_TZ('2013-02-04 21:34:40','+0:00','+5:30')`

Comment: solved by using select * from records where date = CONVERT_TZ('2013-02-04 21:34:40','+5:30','+0:00') .