# Problems filtering django datetime field by month and day

Tags: python, django, datetime, filtering

Can someone explain to me why the following filters are not working at the month and day level?  Filtering by year seems to work, but not the other two.

```
>>> clicks.count()
36
>>> date = clicks[0].created
>>> date.month
2
>>> date.year
2014
>>> date.day
1
>>> clicks.filter(created__month=2)
[]
>>> clicks.filter(created__month=02)
[]
>>> clicks.filter(created__month='02')
[]
>>> clicks.filter(created__month='2')
[]
>>> clicks.filter(created__month=date.month)
[]
>>> clicks.filter(created__day=date.day)
[]
```

A quick update to demonstrate that I am getting the same behavior before creating and dealing with a queryset:

```
>>> clicks = PreviewClick.objects.filter(created__month = 2)
>>> clicks.count()
0
>>> clicks = PreviewClick.objects.filter(created__month = 02)
>>> clicks.count()
0
>>> clicks = PreviewClick.objects.filter(created__month = '02')
>>> clicks.count()
0
>>> clicks = PreviewClick.objects.filter(created__month = '2')
>>> clicks.count()
0
```

Here's more food for thought:

```
>>> clicks = PreviewClick.objects.all()
>>> counter = 0
>>> for click in clicks:
...      if click.created.month == 2:
...           counter += 1
... 
>>> counter
35
```

Comment: How did you create clicks?

Comment: Are you certain you have clicks with 'created' dated of Feb? I just tried this filter on one of our databases, and it worked fine for me.

Comment: It looks like you did <Model>.objects.all() and assigned that to clicks and then are trying to filter it. You probably want to do <Model>.objects.filter(....)

Comment: @user590028 On the second line I grabbed the actual 'created' value for the first item in the queryset and demonstrated that the month value is in fact February.  So the filter should get AT LEAST one record, correct?

Comment: Can you show us that `PreviewClick.objects.all()` has objects in it that have a month of 2

Comment: @Hoopdady lol Yup, I was thinking the same thing.  I updated with that info while you were asking.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your computer and resetting your router :-)

Comment: You don't have anything fancy in your model do you?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same issue as you @zorrotmm.
Django version 1.6.1
Python version 2.7.5
Mac OS


The model field I'm using is models.DateTimeField

.filter(datetime__year=2014) works
.filter(datetime__month=2) doesn't
.filter(datetime__day=25) doesnt't

Will update if I find a solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[@Simon Wilder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043578/1240938) perfectly answer why it's not working, here is how you can actually solve it without disabling TZ support in django

Django document give [instruction](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#database-time-zone-definitions) to install time zone definition to database:

> SQLite: install `pytz` — conversions are actually performed in Python.
>
> PostgreSQL: no requirements (see Time Zones).
>
> Oracle: no requirements (see Choosing a Time Zone File).
>
> MySQL: install `pytz` and load the time zone tables with [`mysql_tzinfo_to_sql`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysql-tzinfo-to-sql.html).

In my case : mysql and Mac Os, following command solve the problem:

```
sudo mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo/ | mysql -u root mysql
```

Comment: Indeed this should be the correct answer. Almost every project should work with timezone aware dates.

Answer (score 26):

I was seeing exactly the same behaviour as you.

If you check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/querysets/#month) for 1.6 and the month queryset. They have added the following paragraph:

> "When USE_TZ is True, datetime fields are converted to the current time zone before filtering. This requires time zone definitions in the database."

If you change the following line in your settings to False, then you should start getting the data back that you're expecting.

```
USE_TZ = False
```

Comment: Hmmm....interesting.  I'll try this and see what happens.  I guess I'm new to dealing with timezones -- I'm trying to filter correctly according to timezone and such, although I'm only using UTC for the actual database records.  I've been doing the timezone calculations in the views.  Do I not need USE_TZ if I'm dealing with it that way?

Comment: I've not dealt with timezones I'm afraid and don't need to for my current project, so my fix about is enough for me at the moment. I hope that this information has given you what you need to get your code working again though.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. It should be:

```
Clicks.objects.filter(created__month=2)
```

(you left off the 'objects' manager)

Comment: I guess I didn't specify that clicks is a queryset that I had already gotten with .all() or filtering by the year 2014, which seems to work.  The filter() function should work the same.  In any case, I'll update the question to demonstrate that I'm getting the same result before creating a queryset.

Answer (score 0):

To update the answer here since I ran into the above issue but none of the solutions worked. Most new mysql installations come pre-installed with tz-info, so the mysql_tzinfo_to_sql command wont really help. And setting TZ_INFO to False isn't really a solution since many need time-zone aware datetime.

So, what worked for me was to create a tz aware datetime object and check against that. Lets say you wanna filter records for today you would do something like,

```
from datetime import datetime
import pytz

today = datetime.now().replace(tzinfo=pytz.UTC).date()   # tz aware datetime object
todays_records = myModel.objects.filter(created__year=today.year, created__month=today.month,created__day=today.day)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Solution for windows, 2022 - how to make django with `USE_TZ=True` be able to filter by month and day, not just year.  Example of now working code: `queryset.filter(created__month=1)`

- download the timezone file from here: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/timezones.html
- make sure you get the right one - for mysql8 I used the file for 5.7
- unzip it - see that it's just a `sql` file
- load it into your mysql database.  something like

`mysql -u root -p mysql < FILEPATH`

- restart mysql service (`control panel` | `administration tools` | `services` | find mysql | `restart`)
- validation: `mysql` | `use mysql` | `select * from time_zone`
- you should see a few thousand entries. If not, it means you didn't load the sql  file in correctly.
- rerun django methods using filtering and it should work.

Note: this is different than `varnothing`'s answer above because on windows, dealing  with filetypes or things like  `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` may be different due to pathing. This one works because you fall back to clear actions like "load this sql file into this db"