# Cannot get object through the defined url in django

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-urls

I was building a blog using django.
My Article model include a field that display publishing date:

```
publish = models.DateTimeField(default = timezone.now)
```

and a get_absolute_url function:

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('article:post_detail', 
                args = [self.publish.year,
                        self.publish.strftime('%m'),
                        self.publish.strftime('%d'),
                        self.slug])
```

This is my view displaying articles:

```
def post_detail(request, year, month, day, post):
    post = get_object_or_404(Article, slug = post,
                                  status = 'published',
                                  publish__year = year,
                                  publish__month = month,
                                  publish__day = day)
return render(request, 'post.html', {'post': post})
```

This is my urls in the blog project:

```
url(r'^article/', include('article.urls', namespace = 'article',app_name = 'article')),
```

and the urls of the article app within the project:

```
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',views.post_detail, name = 'post_detail'),
```

My expected results is like: When the url is article is `/article/2016/04/18/first-article/`, it will display the article published on the specific date with the slug first-article, but instead it displayed:

> No article matches the given query.

When I tasted it using `python manage.py shell`, I found the problem seemed related to the month and day in the publish field:

```
>>> Article.objects.get(pk=1).get_absolute_url()
u'/article/2016/04/18/first-article/'
>>> Article.objects.get(pk=1).publish.year
2016
>>> Article.objects.get(pk=1).publish.month
4
>>> Article.objects.get(pk=1).publish.day
18
```

But when I searched for the article:

```
>>> from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
>>> get_object_or_404(Article, publish__year='2016')
<Article: This is the first article>
>>> get_object_or_404(Article, publish__year='2016', slug='first-article', status='published')
<Article: This is the first article>
>>> get_object_or_404(Article, publish__year='2016', publish__month='04')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
File "/media/psf/Home/Porject/env/my_blog_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 157, in get_object_or_404
  raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
Http404: No Article matches the given query.
>>> get_object_or_404(Article, publish__year='2016', publish__day='18')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/media/psf/Home/Porject/env/my_blog_new/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 157, in get_object_or_404
    raise Http404('No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
Http404: No Article matches the given query.
```

It seemed that anything relate to the month and day didn't work but I was unable to figure out why.
I was using mysql, though I don't think it is related to this problem because my home page worked fine.
Is is the bug of mysql handling datetime field?
I stuck on this problem for several days and appreciated any opinions and tips. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Please modify USE_TZ value into False in settings.py,

```
USE_TZ = False
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22043578/2627126) is original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the article has the flag set to `status = 'published'`?

Comment: Yes, I posted a test using `status = `published`` and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

## This is use in view.py

```
    def post_detail(request,year,month,day,post):
         post=get_object_or_404(Post, 
         publish__year=year,publish__month=month,publish__day=day,status='published', slug=post)
         return render(request, 'blog/post/detail.html', {'post': post})
```

Comment: It would be more helpful if you explained what your code does to answer the question.