# Django 2.1.4 - filter - Why my filter not catch specified year?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I defined `Article` model at models.py. And I defined `created` by `models.DateTimeField` in `Article` class.
I want to get articles by specified year value but I can not catch it by one of my case. But case of other approach is fine. Why ?

models.py

```
class Article(models.Model):

    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

python manage.py shell

```
>>> Article.objects.filter(created__year=2014).all()
<QuerySet []>
>>> for el in Article.objects.all():
...   if el.created.year == 2014:
...     print('2014')
...
2014
>>>
```

Comment: You are using `filter` and `all` together. Try to use just `filter`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21918802/problems-filtering-django-datetime-field-by-month-and-day