# How can i change the timestamp to my own timezone in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

How can i change the timestamp to my own timezone in mysql?

Here is my PHP code below:

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`id` int(6) unsigned not null auto_increment,
`firstname` varchar(30) not null,
`lastname` varchar(30) not null,
`email` varchar(50),
`reg_date` timestamp not null default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ";
```

Comment: is that what you want? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-to-set-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: You will need to edit your conf file if your server is in a different zone.

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira: I am a newbie... and I just saw the link you gave me but I don't know where to put those codes.... can you please help me where should I put them? THanks...

Comment: Okey, first find your "my.cnf" or "my.ini" file (follow that link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2482234/how-to-know-mysql-my-cnf-location). If doesn't exists, please create. And then, you can set up it with that line inside your file -> default_time_zone='+00:00'

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira, I am only using WAMP, and I believe I don't have those options...

Comment: Are you using some MySQL client ? MySQL Workbench / HeidiSQL ?

Comment: @GuilhermeFerreira I am using WAMP and the version of MySQL is 5.5.28....and all I can see is SQL Buddy.....

Comment: Try it BEFORE your 'CREATE' --> SET GLOBAL time_zone = 'your_timezone';

Comment: it didn't work.. there is an error

Answer (score 0):

For a single table and column, you could make a view, converting only the timestamp column from the server's timezone to your actual timezone when you select from the view instead of the table itself.

```
CREATE VIEW `v_mytable` AS
select id
      ,firstname
      ,lastname
      ,email
      ,CONVERT_TZ(regdate,'UCT','US/Pacific') as regdate
 from mytable;
```

If you don't have CONVERT_TZ installed it's outlined over here how to install it:
[MySQL CONVERT_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)