# Converting timezone(convert_tz) in mysql

Tags: mysql, timezone, convert-tz

How does convert_tz works in mysql,while going through some mysql site on web I encountered this function,when I tried replicating it, it is giving me the null value. why isn't this working?.
Following is the script

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
```

this is the output shown on web for convert_tz(),

```
mysql> SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET');
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00','GMT','MET')           |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
| 2004-01-01 13:00:00                                     |
+---------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Try this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz

Comment: And check here [CONVERT_TZ(dt,from_tz,to_tz)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz)

Comment: You can accept the duplicate call-out at the top of your question.