# UTC to America/New_York time zone using MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am storing a date in UTC timezone inside my table but my need is to export a CSV file by converting a date  from UTC to America/New_York time zone.

I have tried with CONVERT_TZ MySQL function, but it's giving null.

How I can convert a date from UTC to America/New_York time zone using  only MySQL and not using PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason behind you are getting null result once you are using CONVERT_TZ MySQL function is that TZ time zone table have not been setup.

You can check that time zone table is set up or not.
select * from mysql.time_zone;
If it's giving null values then you need:

1. insert time zone in MySql if you want to use  CONVERT_TZ MySQL function to convert a date from UTC to America New_Yark time zone.
2. You can run below query without update time_zone table.

SELECT DATE_SUB( order_date, INTERVAL 5 HOUR ) as OrderDate
FROM `TABLE_NAME`

With date format:

SELECT DATE_FORMAT( DATE_SUB( order_date, INTERVAL 5 HOUR ) ,  '%Y-%m-%d %h.%i.%s %p' ) as OrderDate
FROM `TABLE_NAME`

Please have a look similar question.

[MySQL CONVERT_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)

It will help you in "How to insert timezone in MySql".

Answer (score 2):

You have to load the timezone table.

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p password
```

If you do not have superuser access, you can skip friendly timezone names and specify the hours.

```
CONVERT_TZ(date,'+00:00','-07:00')
```