# Set timezone for MYSQL NOW()

Tags: php, mysql

On my server i keep a log of operations and this is tracked using the timestamp generated by MYSQL `NOW()` function.But the problem is that the timestamp generated is in `UTC` and i want the `NOW()` function to generate the timestamp corresponding to my local time for `Asia/Kolkata`. I tried the SET timezone but it is not working

```
$queryt="SET time_zone='Asia/Kolkata'";
mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryt))
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: No you don't.  You want the time to be stored in UTC, and then to convert it to whatever local time you need it to be.  Keep in mind that local time is relative to the user seeing the data.  For example, Asia?Kolkata may be great for you, but I'm in the US.  If you show me something with a datetime stamp, I want to see it relative to my time zone.  In PHP there is robust support with the DATETIME class for converting any datetime value from UTC to whatever timezone you want.

Comment: Okay if thats the case is there some way i can change the datetime displayed in local time format using jquery etc?

Comment: You would be better off formatting the date with PHP. JavaScript does not have a good grasp on timezones

Comment: I agree with Phil, do it server side using DATETIME.  The code for that is simple.  A bigger question is how you are going to figure out the timezone you want.  As I stated, a sophisticated approach would be to try and figure out the end user's timezone using their IP.  If however you want to just show everything in 'Asia/Kokata' that is trivial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is not clear but if you want to change date and time value from UTC to your time zone, you can use

```
CONVERT_TZ(date, 'UTC',  'Asia/Kolkata')
```

You can select the UTC date and time value in your time zone:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ(date, 'UTC',  'Asia/Kolkata') AS local FROM table
```

If CONVERT_TZ function does not work, you need to install time zones (time zones should be already stored in MySQL). One note is that you need to store UTC value in your database and later convert to whatever time zone you want.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SET GLOBAL time_zone = "Asia/Kolkata";
SET time_zone = "+05:30";
SET @@session.time_zone = "+05:30";
```

Comment: SET GLOBAL time_zone = '+5:30';

Answer (score 0):

When you're using PHP (as the OP), if you can't install the CONVERT_TZ function, another option to convert a timezone is to use an offset interval.

**In PHP:**

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Kolkata'); // Set timezone if different from default
$TZ_OFFSET = date('Z')/3600; // Timezone offset in hours from UTC (allows for DST where applicable)
```

Then run **MySQL query** using that offset variable:

```
SELECT (modified_date + interval $TZ_OFFSET hour) AS modified_date FROM table;
```

This is useful if you want to use "NOW()" on a database server set to UTC, but want to query date/times in a local timezone in an application.