# Convert system timezone in mysql returning null

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to convert mysql current timezone, to another one. But I'm getting Null as answer:

```
select *, CONVERT_TZ(NOW(),@@session.time_zone, 'America/Sao Paulo')
from historical_prices;
```

This is my query.

How can I fix this?

Comment: have you checked this?looks like your problem. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL CONVERT\_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)