# How do convert this redshift query to MySQL about date

Tags: mysql

So I want to convert this redshift query to MySQL. This is about getting the date truncating it then converting it to string

I tried doing this

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ('material_boxes.created','UTC','America/New_York'),'%m') AS "month_only" FROM material_boxes
```

The redshift query is this

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(DATE_TRUNC('month', CONVERT_TIMEZONE('UTC', 'America/New_York', material_boxes.created )), 'YYYY-MM') AS "month_only" FROM material_boxes
```

The result should be the month only.

Comment: And what is wrong with your current MySQL query attempt?

Comment: Please read [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz) which discusses how to setup the MySQL timezone tables.

Answer (score 0):

I did it by removing '' in material_boxes.created and changing "%m" to "%M" for the string for month.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(CONVERT_TZ('material_boxes.created','UTC','America/New_York'),'%m') AS "month_only" FROM material_boxes
```