# Handling Daylight Saving Time in MySQL CONVERT_TZ

Tags: mysql

I store all the dates in my database as UTC. This to stay consistent and avoid confusion when my application would be used by different countries.

Sometimes I need to convert to my local timezone `Europe/Brussels` though.

```
select CONVERT_TZ('2021-08-13 14:40:55', '+00:00', 'Europe/Brussels') from sale;
```

Returns `NULL`.

So I tried

```
select CONVERT_TZ('2021-08-13 14:40:55', '+00:00', '+01:00') from sale;
```

Which does work, but still returns the wrong time. The European Union - for some ridiculous reason - still has a 'Daylight Saving Time' resulting in one hour being added during the summer.

How would I handle that?

Comment: no it is added in spring and removed in autumn somertime began this year 27. March and ends at 31 October

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL CONVERT\_TZ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523286/mysql-convert-tz)